OpenTelemetry on Gunicorn and Falcon not showing spans properly
I have an application running with a combination of Falcon and Gunicorn. I am trying to use OpenTelemetry to instrument it and send traces to Jaeger.
The following is my code:
pyproject.toml:
opentelemetry-distro = {extras = ["otlp"], version = "0.44b0" }
opentelemetry-instrumentation = "0.44b0"
opentelemetry-instrumentation-falcon = "0.44b0"

gunicorn_conf.py:
from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.proto.grpc.trace_exporter import OTLPSpanExporter
from opentelemetry.sdk.resources import Resource
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import BatchSpanProcessor

def post_fork(server, worker):
    from opentelemetry.instrumentation.auto_instrumentation import sitecustomize
    server.log.info("Worker spawned (pid: %s)", worker.pid)

    resource = Resource.create(attributes={
        "service.name": "my-app"
    })

    trace.set_tracer_provider(TracerProvider(resource=resource))
    span_processor = BatchSpanProcessor(
        OTLPSpanExporter(endpoint=telemetry_endpoint, insecure=telemetry_insecure)
    )
    trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(span_processor)

And the launch command:
OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES=service.name={app_name} OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_ENDPOINT={telemetry_endpoint} OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_METRICS_ENDPOINT={telemetry_endpoint} OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_INSECURE={telemetry_insecure} OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER=otlp OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER=none opentelemetry-instrument gunicorn -c gunicorn_conf.py

So the application runs and then the traces appear on Jaeger but shows it like a single function call and not multiple calls even if there is a db call or an external api call.


I think you need to propagate the trace context manually in your application code. I run into a similar issue. I took the traceparentid from the header (in my case the header of a receiving kafka message):
        value = headers_dict['traceparent']
        value_string =value.decode('utf-8')
        carrier ={'traceparent':value_string}
        ctx = TraceContextTextMapPropagator().extract(carrier=carrier)

The following code then uses an http call so I also made sure to provide the ctx in the generated trace, something like this:
def getLocationDetails(self, ctx, headers):
        tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)
      
        with tracer.start_span("get geo data", context=ctx):
            try:
                response = requests.request("GET", self.url, headers=headers, data=payload)
                ...
                return location_data
            
            except HTTPError as http_err:
                
                return http_err

And then also include the ctx in the tracer I use to create a span for sending out a kafka message.
  def send(self, topic, key, message,ctx, header):
        tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)
        with tracer.start_span("send kafka message", context=ctx):
            self.producer.send(topic, value=message, key=key, headers=header)

For me propagating the traceparent worked out and I am seeing now all my spans in one trace. I am not sure if that is the best solution, but I hope it helps.


So the application runs and then the traces appear on Jaeger but shows it like a single function call and not multiple calls even if there is a db call or an external api call.

Looking at your pyproject.toml, the only instrumentation being installed is opentelemetry-instrumentation-falcon (and whatever dependencies that pulls in). In order to trace other components, like outgoing API requests through an HTTP client or db calls, you need to install the relevant instrumentations for those components. See Supported libraries and frameworks or you can search on PyPI for instrumentations. You can also try using the opentelemetry-bootstrap command as described here to automatically install relevant instrumentations.
